# What is the difference between sys admin and [sa] account in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, roles, privileges

In SQL Server Management Studio, I was not able to access database diagrams even when I was logged in as sys admin. I was getting this error

> could not obtain information about windows nt group/user

I fixed this error by changing the database owner to [sa].

How is it that [sa] has more privilege than sys admin?

Comment: It's nothing to do with privileges of the accounts themselves -- `sa` is a built-in account that doesn't need to be verified against the OS account databases, while Windows accounts do need that. The inability to verify Windows accounts is typically due to SQL Server being unable to register a service principal name (SPN) with the domain controller (but there can be other causes).

Answer (score 2):

1. `sa` is a user while `sysadmin` is a role/privilege
2. `sysadmin` has all privileges and `sa` is a default user with privileges similar to `sysadmin`

Privileges are associated with user.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: sa is not user, but login.

Comment: Is it user or a login?